# Chaining Python StringIO

Tags: python, stringio

Is there a means by which I can add processing to an `io.TextIOBase` subclass and produce another `io.TextIOBase` subclass? For example, if I want to convert from a string of Octal characters to Binary characters, I could do this with a generator function, but I'm interested in being able to read an arbitrary number of characters from the resultant stream, so this approach doesn't really work:

```py
oct_hex = {
        "0": "000",
        "1": "001",
        "2": "010",
        "3": "011",
        "4": "100",
        "5": "101",
        "6": "110",
        "7": "111",
}

def _oct_to_bin(messaage: io.StringIO) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
        while char := messaage.read(1):
            yield oct_hex[char]
        raise StopIteration
```

What I'd like to achieve is something with a signature like, although the exact type of stream doesn't really matter:

```py
def _oct_to_bin(message: io.StringIO) -> io.StringIO
```

I realise that I can use `.getValue()` to grab the entire stream in a single string. Process that outside of `io.StringIO` and then create a new `io.StringIO` from the resultant string. I'd ideally like an approach that is a bit more stream friendly and loads the necessary data on demand and could potentially be adapted to other classes in the `io` module.

Comment: Do you actually need to construct another ``io.StringIO`` or just any character stream?

Comment: That's a great shout - just any character stream would very much work.